# Angular 2+ save HTML with style to PDF adds black section

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I want to save some HTML with some CSS styles to a pdf file using https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf from an angular 4 app.

My code is similar to the one shown in this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/hAd0lPjyWs0pJOL3sAOp?p=preview

My print method:

```
print() {
    let innerContents = document.getElementById('print-section');
    let doc = new jsPDF();
     doc.addHTML(innerContents, () => {
       doc.save('Receipt.pdf')
    })
  }
```

But from some reason the downloaded pdf file is showing some black sections instead of the desired html as you can see in the bellow snippet.
Any idea why this happends??

[image]

And this is the pdf from my app:

[image]